# C++ checking if a node is a root in a binary tree

Tags: c++

Here's a generic algorithm to check the depth of a binary tree:

```
int maxDepth(TreeNode* root) {

    if(root){ 

        return 1 + max( maxDepth(root->left), maxDepth(root->right)); 

    }
```

How does the `if(root)` condition work?

I am assuming it means `if(root = a value of type root)` but am unsure how to use it in other situations.

Comment: Read a tutorial, the use of pointer values in a boolean context is explained there.

Comment: thanks, do you have any suggestions?

Comment: `if(root)` is equivalent to `if(root != nullptr)`.

Comment: Agreed, @UlrichEckhardt, though there are good tutorials and bad tutorials. Any you recommend? (It can be HARD to find good tutorials sometimes unless you already know the topic well.)

Comment: I'd check the C++ FAQ or search the web.

Comment: The check does not test if a pointer is pointing to a correct or valid memory location.  There is a possibility that a pointer is not null and points to an invalid location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You showed this and asked:

> Here's a generic algorithm to check the depth of a binary tree:
> int maxDepth(TreeNode* root) {

```
if(root){ 
    return 1 + max( maxDepth(root->left), maxDepth(root->right)); 
 }
```

> How does the if(root) condition work?
>
> I am assuming it means if(root = a value of type root) but am unsure how to use it in other situations.

Let us look at `if(root)` here the variable root is defined within the function definition as a pointer variable to a `TreeNode` object. When one calls this function they in turn pass a pointer to a `TreeNode`. The `if()` statement is a check to see if this is a "valid" pointer. So it checks to see if the value of `root` which is a pointer to a `TreeNode` object has a valid memory address stored within this variable. If the memory address is invalid this will return false, otherwise it will return true and execute the code that is inside the scope of this if statement.

Another words the statement:

```
return 1 + max( maxDepth( root->left), maxDepth( root->right ) );
```

will only happen if `root` is a valid pointer with a valid memory address, otherwise it will skip over this if statement.

Your last assumption is not correct. This is not a check of a valid type. This is a check to see if the pointer itself is valid.

**EDIT**

I would also like to note that even if `root` is valid that this does not mean that the actual memory address stored in this variable is 100% an address to an actual `TreeNode` object, it only verifies that it is valid. It is uncommon to see something of this nature happen but in some circumstances where outside code is doing other work, it may be possible that some undefined behavior may have happened and a valid memory address was assigned into this variable where the memory address that was assigned is not the one that you were expecting.

An example of a memory address being invalid would be either -1 or the largest possible unsigned int value. This is what would cause the `if( root )` check to fail and skip over the statement. Memory addresses are typically referenced in hex numbers so if you was expecting a `TreeNode` object to be located in the range of say 0x000000AA - 0x000000FF and the memory address that was actually stored in `root` was outside of that bounds this if check would still pass and execution will continue into the scope of the statement since this pointer is still considered valid with a valid memory address even if it isn't the one you were expecting. Then this is where you would possibly get corruption on the heap, unhandled exceptions, and undefined behavior or other types of errors or crashes. This is just something to be aware of when working with raw pointers.

Answer (score 3):

The condition `root` is true if `root != NULL` and false if `root == NULL`.

An example of other use of it: checking the return value of `fopen`

```
#include <cstdio>

int main(void) {
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("hoge", "r");
    if (fp) {
        // successfully opened the file
        fclose(fp);
    } else {
        // failed to open the file
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Prefer `nullptr` over `NULL`.

Answer (score 2):

```
if(root)
```

is the same as saying

```
if(root != nullptr)
```

or

```
if(root != NULL)
```

or

```
if(root != 0)
```

It's a way to make sure that root contains a valid address before trying to use it.

What it does in this specific example is to stop the traversal of a branch when it reaches an empty node. So the code inside the if statement will be executed only if root is not empty.